# How to mock a koin injected bean in android activity test and capture lambda given as parameter of this mock?

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, mocking, koin

I spent many time to find a smart way to mock Koin bean in android activity. Unfortunatly none was satisfying ... until the koin-1.0.0-alpha22 launches

Thanks @arnaudgiuliani.

A full sample can be found here [AndroidTestKoin sample project](https://github.com/patrice-conil/testKoinMockBean)

Hope this helps
Patrice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample demonstrates how to use koin declareMock() in androidTest to capture then call lambda given as parameter of one mocked bean.

```
class CastManager() : ICastManager {
    private val devices = HashMap<String, Device>()

    init {
        devices["MyDevice"] = Device("MyDevice", "0000")
    }

    override fun getDevices(onSuccess: (List<Device>) -> Unit, onError: (Int) -> Unit){
        onSuccess(devices.values as List<Device>)
    }
}
```

The main activity needs an instance of castManager in its onCreate.

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private val castManager by inject<ICastManager>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        castManager.getDevices(
                        {devices: List<Device> -> onSuccess(devices)},
                        {error: Int -> onError(error)} )

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
    }
...
```

The real bean is declared as usual like this ...

```
val applicationModules = listOf(
        module {
            single() { CastManager() as ICastManager }
        }
)
```

And koin is started by the application

```
open class MyApplication: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        startKoin(this, applicationModules, logger = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) AndroidLogger() else EmptyLogger())
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```

Since koin-1.0.0-alpha23 we can use declareMock() to inject mock instance

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityTest: KoinTest {

    val myBeanToMock: ICastManager by inject()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    //As interaction with mock starts in activity's onCreate we can't launch it before mock configuration
    val rule = object : ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java, false, false) {}

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        loadKoinModules(applicationModules)
        declareMock<ICastManager>()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        rule.finishActivity()
        closeKoin()
    }

    @Test
    fun verifyMockInjection() {
        // We want to capture lambda callbacks given as argument to the mock to interact with it's caller

        doAnswer {
            //arguments[0] is the onSuccess method
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            (it.arguments[0] as (List<Device>) -> Unit).invoke(listOf(Device("myMockedDevice", "2000")))
        }.whenever(myBeanToMock).getDevices(any(), any())

        rule.launchActivity(null)
        BaristaVisibilityAssertions.assertDisplayed(R.string.my_mocked_device)
    }
}
```

createMock() from Koin version 1.0.0-alpha22 was replaced by declareMock to avoid conflict with Mockito's createMock